# Can not change the speed of the animationTree

Tags: animation, godot

I want to change the speed of the animationTree in order to make the player smoother, but end up getting stuck with it.

I'm currently using the animationState, which is suitable for my top-down 2D game, here is the picture if I'm mistaken:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CjLO.png)

English is not my native language but I will try my best to give everyone information, ask me if you guys want to know other information as well! Really thanks for the help